# Can't delete Foreign Key in Astah despite deleting line between boxes

Tags: database, foreign-keys, astah

I'm designing an ER diagram for an assignment, and I have connected two tables, which automatically updated their foreign keys, now despite unconnecting those classes, I can't delete the foreign key. I can't delete it even if I delete the class that it is referencing. |

Error: Foreign Key cannot be deleted directly. If you delete the relationship, the foreign key will be deleted.

So how do I delete the relationship? The line between the boxes is gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Relationships list can be found in Relationship tab of the entity. You can delete it by pressing the Delete button.

[image]